# Finding unique words and their count

Tags: python

Can I convert strings into small letters without running a loop on 'words' in below code?

```
class TextFileHandeling:
        def __init__(self,path,mode):
           self.path=path
           self.mode=mode


    def reading_file(self):
        file_read= open(self.path,self.mode)
        lines=file_read.read() 
        words=lines.split()   #split strings into words
        return words
        file_read.close()      


    def writing_file(self,words):
        unique=[]
        file_write= open(self.path,self.mode)
        small_letters=[]

        **for i in words:
            small_letters.append(i.lower())**

        for j in small_letters:
            if j not in unique:
                unique.append(j)
                file_write.write(f"{str(j)} {small_letters.count(j)}\n")
        return file_write
        file_write.close()

read_file=TextFileHandeling('D:\\python_practise\\read.txt','r')
write_file=TextFileHandeling('D:\\python_practise\\reader.txt','w')

words= read_file.reading_file()
write_file.writing_file(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already looping over your `small_letter` list so why not just convert the word to lowercase in that loop only.

```
for word in words:
    if word.lower() not in unique:
        pass
```

also I am not aware of lower casing the words without looping over the list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you have return clause after the return statement you are not closing your file, so

```
   def reading_file(self):
        file_read= open(self.path,self.mode)
        lines=file_read.read() 
        words=lines.split()  
        return words
        file_read.close()
```

must become:

```
 def reading_file(self):
        file_read= open(self.path,self.mode)
        lines=file_read.read() 
        words=lines.split()  
        file_read.close() 
        return words
```

I also suggest you to change the name of the function in get_words, because the real functionality of the function is to give you the listed words, not to read the file.

In order to put all the word to lower use the function map:

```
def my_lower(str_in):
    return str_in.lower()
small_letters = map(my_lower, words)
```

moreover, since it looks like you are using unique as a set, hence you use it if something has already been written consider changing the data structure of unique in a set. Here you can find documentation of sets:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Answer (score -1):

This should work perfectly:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_letters

with open('somefile.txt') as fin :
    text = fin.read()    # add .lower() if you need lower case only

# filter out the puctuation
filtered = [t if t in ascii_letters else ' ' for t in text.lower()]

Counter(filtered.split())
```